# du, find and load average

Tags: linux, find, load-average

I have a complex directory structure with lot of small files in it. 
like:

```
/opt/data/1000/45/32/2009/10/15/76543.zip
```

When I launch a `du` or `find` on this directory (/opt/data/) my server load increases a lot (0,5 --> 25) and my system doesn't respond any more.

Can I "slow down" the execution of the du/find command to keep my system accessible? I don't care if the command takes 3 days to run :-) I've tried with `nice -n 19` with no success...

Thank you !

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the problem is that DU is disk I/O intensive, and I think NICE will only prioritize CPU resources. I don't really have an answer, but I though that this comment could help.

Comment: yes bob, you're right. the problem is I/O...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use "ionice" to be more gentle to the system.

Ex:

```
$ ionice du /opt/data
```

You can even set the io scheduling on a pid:

```
$ ionice -c 3 -p 1023
```

See man page for more info on how to use "ionice"

Comment: +1, I didn't know ionice existed! Very nice!

Comment: Thank you! I've tried... but nothing change. Note: this tool is in debian "schedutils" package.

Answer (score 1):

I would do both ionice and nice:

So after running ionice, then run renice:

```
renice -n 20 -p 1023
```

You could also just launch the process with nice in the first place.